# Add extra row to total but only for one product

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart

I want to add one extra row on the total of Shopping cart and checkout pages but only for one product when that product will be in the shopping cart.

**My requirement is to add the fixed shipping price for only one product that will be plus with other shipping if that product is in the cart.**

[image]

Any help will be appreciated!!

Thanks.

Comment: Do you what to add a row or add a fix amount to current shipping cost?

Comment: My requirement is to add the fixed shipping price for only one product that will be plus with other shipping if that product is in the cart and I think I can do this by adding one more fixed amount row under Shipping & Handling (See the image above). But this shipping only for one product & applied when that product in the cart.?? I hope this will make sense now. Please let me know how I can do this?? @R.S

Comment: Take a look at http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/